# Compilation Failure : cannot access LoggingEventAware [ERROR] class file for org.slf4j.spi.LoggingEventAware not found on mvn clean install -U

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-11, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have upgraded the spring boot version from 2.3.5 to 2.7.5 , resolved most of the dependency versions. But when i do the maven clean install , i received the compilation failure error : cannot access LoggingEventAware
[ERROR]   class file for org.slf4j.spi.LoggingEventAware not found

But i do not see any error in the java file - LoggingConfiguration.java.

When i just do reload of project to resolve all the dependencies - it gives error for maven plugin : Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.1.1

I am not sure what is the issue. I have tried to restart IntelliJ after invalidate cache and also cleared the .m2 repository .Nothing helps. Please suggest your inputs how to resolve the same.

Here is the sample pom.xml

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

   
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-release-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-release-plugin.version>
        <maven-scm-provider-gitexe.version>1.9.5</maven-scm-provider-gitexe.version>
        <junit.platform.version>4.13.0</junit.platform.version>
       
        <logback-json-classic>0.1.5</logback-json-classic>
        <logback-jackson.version>0.1.5</logback-jackson.version>

    </properties>

</project> ```
````

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade to `slf4j-api:2.0.4` or later to address this issues. Something in your dependency tree is likely pulling an older version.

Comment: 2.0.9 caused same error and had to upgrade to 2.0.12 for fixing this after migrating from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3.0.13.

Answer (score 0):

While updating a project to Spring Boot 3.0.1, I came across the same issue.
Here is what worked for me:

1. Exclude logback-classic sub-dependency of spring-boot-starter-web.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
               <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add an earlier dependency of logback with version 1.2.11

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.11</version>
   </dependency>
   ```